# How to calculate this integral containing a ArcTanh function?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'm trying to calculate this integral :

$$I(z,k,a)= \int_1^\infty t^2 \operatorname{ArcTanh}  \left(\sqrt{\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}} \dfrac{k}{z}\right)\, e^{-a\,t} \, dt$$

Where :

- $\operatorname{ArcTanh(\cdots)}$ : is the inverse hyperbolic tangent function.
- $z=x+i\,y$ : is a complex with the assumption $y\ll x$
- $k$ and $a$ are reals $> 0$

Please, how do I go about this ? Is there any tricks that can be applied ?

Is there a way to transform this integral in a form of Plemelj-Dirac Formula ?

$$
I(z,k,a)=P \int_1^{t_0} \cdots\cdots \, dt \pm i \pi \big( \cdots \cdots \big)_{t=t_0}$$

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I doubt you'll get a closed form.  For asymptotics as $a \to \infty$ you should be able to use Watson's lemma.

Comment: Please, I'm a physicist and I have no idea about these theorems and lemma.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson's_lemma

Comment: Please, can someone give me some suggestions for evaluating the integral above ?

Comment: For particular values, you can use numerical integration methods.  The exponential factor ensures that $t \to \infty$ is not a problem.  For example, you could try the NAG routine [d01amc](http://www.nag.com/numeric/CL/nagdoc_cl23/html/D01/d01amc.html).

Comment: @Robert Israel, sorry, it's very complicated for me to use this. Numerical solutions are already calculated, but I would like to calculate the symbolic solution for solving a non linear equation. Thank's.